# Value rendered by Controller not getting displayed

Tags: symfony, twig

So I'm working with Symfony 4.4 and I'm facing an issue here.

I have the following script responsible for getting the value of an input tag and sending it back as json to the controller

```
 {% if summoner is defined %}
                let res = {{ summoner.summonerLevel }}
            {% endif %}
            $("#valid-summoner").click(function () {
                let data = {'sumoner_name':$("#riot-summoner-input").val()}
                let url = `/coach/`

            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest

            xhr.open("GET", url)
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))
            console.log(data)
            function loadXMLDoc()
            {
                document.getElementById("display-summonerLevel").innerHTML = `Summoner Level: <h2>${res}</h2>`
            }
            loadXMLDoc();

        });
```

I have a controller method responsible for rendering the index page that's receiving this json and extracting the content and using it to render the page again but with another option which is that value.

```
...
$data = json_decode($request->getContent());

        if(isset($data->sumoner_name) && !empty($data->sumoner_name)){

            // We return the code
            return $this->render('coach/index.html.twig', [
                'coaches' => $coaches, 'summoner'=> $this->showSummoner($data->sumoner_name),
                'current_user'=>$currentUser, 'combined'=>$call->fetchCoachRating($coaches)
            ]);
        }else{
            return $this->render('coach/index.html.twig', [
                'coaches' => $coaches,
                'current_user'=>$currentUser, 'combined'=>$call->fetchCoachRating($coaches)
            ]);
        }
```

I don't know if this is actually the way you're supposed to do it. But it certainly isn't working..

`console.log(data)` in the script give back the following output

```
(index):445 {sumoner_name: 'YàKûZa'}sumoner_name: "YàKûZa"[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I'm not sure what I can do here

Comment: If i understand your question correctly you can try return view('coach/index.html.twig', [
                'coaches' => $coaches,
                'current_user'=>$currentUser, 'combined'=>$call->fetchCoachRating($coaches)
            ]);

Comment: @AltafHussain What's view Symfony doesn't recognize it

Comment: sorry my mistake i thought its laravel

Comment: @AltafHussain The problem is the first time when $data->summoner_name is empty or hasn't been received yet I'm rendering the page without passing the 'summoner' option. But in the javascript I'm returning it and expecting the page to render again with the new variable when it definitely isn't going to. I don't know how to achieve that

Comment: What does `var_dump($request->getContent())` return then

Comment: @DarkBee Wow it actually didn't return anything. Nothing was displayed in the console